# How to get value of a match from Select-String in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to get a version number from an output but I'm getting whole line.

```
$version = $output | Select-String -Pattern "r\d\d\d\d\d"
```

Which gives me line where it has found my pattern eq:

> "Version of your application is r11111 consider updating"

How to get only value of version eq:

> r11111

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
$version = ($output | Select-String -Pattern "(?:\d+)").Matches.Value
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Regex Match:

```
$output -match "r\d{5}"; $version = $Matches[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, found solution by myself but yours is more elegant and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution my self, using regex

```
$version = [regex]::match(($output | Select-String -Pattern "-r\d\d\d\d\d"),
                           "\-([^\)]+)\-").Groups[1].Value
```